# VendInvoiceJour.InvoiceAccount <- VendTable.AccountNum relation

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have following situation:
I need to join VendInvoiceJour.InvoiceAccount <- VendTable.AccountNum and take VendTable.Vendgroup.
In all cases (queries,or even views) Dynamics ax joins tables VendInvoiceJour.OrderAccount<- VendTable.AccountNum not 
VendInvoiceJour.InvoiceAccount <- VendTable.AccountNum.
I`m trying to use this kind of query:

```
qBdSVendJour = element.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(VendInvoiceJour));
qBdSVendTbl = qBdSVendJour.addDataSource(tablenum(VendTable));
qBdSVendTbl.relations(true);
qBdSVendTbl.joinMode(JoinMOde::InnerJoin);
qBdSVendTbl.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);

qBdSVendTbl.addLink(
    FieldNum(VendInvoiceJour,InvoiceAccount)
    ,FieldNum(VendTable,AccountNum)
); //(Dynamics ax automatically corrects InvoiceAccount to orderaccount 
   //in reports if trying this link in morphx)
```

Comment: Please clean up you code with <pre> or <code>.

Comment: @Jan Never format your code using HTML on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the line:

```
  *qBdSVendTbl.relations(true);*
```

then you won't need to add:

```
  *BdSVendJour.clearDynalink();*
```

To be sure that the actual query is the expected print the conent of:

```
  *qBdSVendJour.toString();*
```

Answer (score 0):

`qBdSVendJour.clearDynalink()` will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry. My culprit was qBdSVendTbl.relations(true);  i had to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the statement qBdSVendTbl.relations(true) will have AX evaluate the defined relations on the tables in question and use them regardless.